# How do I prevent the table view from producing doubles?

Tags: ios, swift

I am refreshing the table view by pulling down. It refreshes the array of songs stored in parse. I get a version of the array when the app starts, but when I add stuff to the array and then refresh it, the program adds everything again plus the new things. So now I have everything repeating twice, except the new item. How do I avoid the repeats?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 getSongs()

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.table.addSubview(refreshControl)

           // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}


 func getSongs(){
    let retrieve = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
    retrieve.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var object = objects as! [PFObject]
        if(error == nil){
            for i in 0...object.count-1{
                //self.ret.append(object[i].valueForKey("user") as! String)

                if (object[i].valueForKey("user")!.objectId == currentUserID){
                    //print(object[i].valueForKey("title") as! String)
                    self.ret.append(object[i].valueForKey("title") as! String)
                    self.ter.append(object[i].valueForKey("artist") as! String)
                    print(self.ret)
                    print(self.ter)
                }
            }
        }

    })

}

func refresh(sender: AnyObject){
    getSongs()
    table.reloadData()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: tell us which data set is used to make tableview's cells

Comment: ret is the cell string and ter is the cell subtitle

Comment: make it clean ur data set before u append new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.ret = []
self.ter = []
```

Place these before you begin appending new data to clear the arrays.

Comment: Should I place them in the function or the didload?

Answer (score 2):

@Tim is right. You have to refresh data before.

```
func getSongs(){
    let retrieve = PFQuery(className: "Pointer")
    retrieve.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var object = objects as! [PFObject]
        if(error == nil){

            // refresh data 
            self.ret = []
            self.ter = []

            for i in 0...object.count-1{
                //self.ret.append(object[i].valueForKey("user") as! String)

                if (object[i].valueForKey("user")!.objectId == currentUserID){
                    //print(object[i].valueForKey("title") as! String)
                    self.ret.append(object[i].valueForKey("title") as! String)
                    self.ter.append(object[i].valueForKey("artist") as! String)
                    print(self.ret)
                    print(self.ter)
                }
            }
        }

    })

}
```